# Error: unexpected character after line continuation character

Tags: python

> SyntaxError: unexpected character after line continuation character

i get this error at line one in my code

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
from matplotlib import style

style.use('fivethirtyeight')

fig = plt.figure()
axl = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

define animate(i):
    graph_data = open('data.txt', 'r').read()
    lines = graph_data.split('/n')
    xs = []
    ys =[]
    for line in lines:
        if len(line) > 1:
            x, y = line.split(',')
            xs.append(x)
            ys.append(y)

    ax1.clear()        
    ax1.plot(xs, ys)

ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=1000)
plt.show()
```

why?

Comment: `'/n'` looks wrong, perhaps you meant `'\n'`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `def animate` not `define animate`